# Outlook REST api GetUsers intermittently returning empty array

Tags: outlook-restapi

We are currently using this REST call:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/people/?$top=1000
```

We are intermittently getting a `200 OK` but without any data.  After a day or so, with the same user login we are able to retrieve a list of correct response.

Had anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: Does dropping the `$top` to a small chunk make a difference?

Comment: We haven't try that since this issue started.  Worth a try.  Thanks for the suggestion